# %s variable not working in Magento

Tags: magento

I always use %s variable as a placeholder when there is error or success such as this code:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('module')
->__('Hi %s, there is an error', $name));
```

The problem is: sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Surely the $name does contain a valid string value (I've var_dump it many times). Do you know why?

Comment: What are you seeing instead? Generally, we need something more than "it doesn't work" to know how to properly diagnose a problem.

Comment: Still %s as opposed to $name.

Answer (score 19):

As others have noted, you're not limited to one argument in your translated string. Some examples:

*One argument, in one place:*

```
Mage::helper('module')->__('Hi %s, there is an error', $name);
```

*Two arguments, in two places:*

```
Mage::helper('module')->__('Hi %s, there is an error with code %s', $name, $code);
```

*One argument, in two places:*

```
Mage::helper('module')->__('Hi %1$s, there is an error. Your name is %1$s', $name);
```

*Two arguments, swapping places:*

```
// Template or block file
Mage::helper('module')->__('Hi %1$s %2$s, there is an error', $firstname, $lastname);

// CSV translation
"Hi %1$s %2$s, there is an error", "%2$s, %1$s received an error"
```

Documentation on the PHP function being used to power this can be found here: [vsprintf](http://php.net/vsprintf)

(PS: The double-quoting that [knase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1844561/knase) is talking about only applies to your CSV file, where a double-quote is an escaped single quote.)

Comment: You can also escape a `%` the same way you would with `sprintf()` in PHP. Use two percent signs to escape one, like `Mage::helper('module')->__('Finished %d%%', $int);` which would return something like `Finished 17%`

Answer (score 3):

%s  varible work in translate magento. You can write in .csv translate file such as in example:

```
"Hi %s, there is an error","An error is %s"
```

Or if you use "%s" for translate you must write double slashe twiсe for shield. Look example:

```
"Hi ""%s"", there is an error.","An error is ""%s""."
```

You write for this translate:

```
Mage::helper('module')->__('Hi "%s", there is an error', $name);
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Magento are you using?  In current version of Magento, the variable replacement happens here

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php
...
//array_unshift($args, $translated);
//$result = @call_user_func_array('sprintf', $args);

$result = @vsprintf($translated, $args);
...
```

I imagine dropping some debugging statement in there could help lead to a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: I'm using CE 1.8.0.0. I'll try to look at your suggestion. It's new though for me. For now, I'm still using %s variable replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in the csv file you use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'`.

Incorrect:

`'Welcome %s', 'Hello %s'`

Correct:

`"Welcome %s", "Hello %s"`

Answer (score -3):

Wow, it seems if there is more than one %s, the translation won't work. So it must be only one %s for the translation to work properly.